# PDO does not rewind bound stream

Tags: mysql, pdo

PDO does not rewind bound stream

I am using PHP PDO and MySQL.

I am trying to execute a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query,
binding stream to two placeholders in the query.

Here is a code example:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @param PDO $pdo
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param resource $fileContent
 */
function persistFromStream(PDO $pdo, string $fileName, $fileContent): void
{
    $query = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO files (name, content)
        VALUES (:name, :content)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content = :contentSecondTime
        SQL;

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindParam('content', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->bindParam('contentSecondTime', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Insert works fine.
"ON DUPLICATE" logic does not work fine: it writes empty string (`''`) into `content` column.

I suspect that this happens because PDO does not rewind my stream (`$fileContent`) when using it second time (in the "`DUPLICATE` clause").

If I copy the stream, both INSERT and ON DUPLICATE will work fine:

```php
/**
 * @param PDO $pdo
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param resource $fileContent
 * @return void
 */
function persistFromStreamWithCopying(PDO $pdo, string $fileName, $fileContent): void
{
    $contentCopy = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    stream_copy_to_stream($fileContent, $contentCopy);
    rewind($fileContent);
    rewind($contentCopy);

    $query = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO files (name, content)
        VALUES (:name, :content)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content = :contentSecondTime
        SQL;

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

    $statement->bindParam(':name', $fileName);
    $statement->bindParam('content', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->bindParam('contentSecondTime', $contentCopy, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

The question is: *Can I bind a single stream twice in a query, so PDO rewinds it somehow?*

Thank you for your attention.

Kind regards.

Comment: You can only do this if you emulate prepares (see the 3rd and 4th answers to the dupe). Otherwise, just call 1 `payload1` and the other `payload2` and bind them separately

Comment: Hello, Nick. I have update the question according to your suggestion. It does not fix the issue; I think it's not about names of the parameters, it's about the stream not being rewind after being read for the first binding.

Comment: If that's the issue you should just be able to read it into another variable and bind to that instead.

Comment: Dear Nick, I know that I can read it into another variable and bind to that instead. The question is: can I execute the query without creating another variable?

Comment: Have you tried using `bindValue`? I've reopened the question since I agree it's not about the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `bindValue` does not help.

Comment: I'd write this with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content = VALUES(content)` without the `contentSecondTime` parameter. It'll just remember the value you tried to insert into that column and reuse it. Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Hi, Bill. The solution with `VALUES(content)` works! Thank you. Care to create an answer? I will accept it.